# Do we really know what does probability mean?

Tags: probability, bayesian, definition, frequentist

When I read debates or listen to videos about probabilities and bayesians versus frequentists, it reminds me like a lot the question of "do we know what infinite means?" (related to the Continuum hypothesis), with the conclusion that "we understand what countable infinite means (natural numbers) but we don't understand what uncountable infinite means (real numbers and beyond)", so we can talk about the first using a natural language, but we need hardcoded symbolic axioms and rewrite rules to talk about the second.

If there's so many discussions between bayesians and frequentists about their viewpoints, is that non-ending debate telling us that we don't actually know what exactly does probability mean?

Comment: This kind of invitation to join a "non-ending debate" is not on topic here on CV.  Please consult our [help] for the kinds of questions we can address.  BTW, are you aware that almost all statisticians agree on a [standard set of probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms)?  There is an important distinction between probability *theory* and how probability might be *applied* to practical problems.  Overlooking that distinction can only lead to confusion.